# Wordpress: Use PHP Function based on Blog URL & Adding To MU-Plugins

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin for an MU site. The MU site has about a few hundred blogs, but there are three types of blogs and they are named as:

blogname/sportstype1
blogname/sportstype2
blogname/sportstype3
blogname/celebritytype1
blogname/celebritytype2
etc.

I need to make two functions, one for type1, and the other function for the rest (type2/3). I have a function I made, wanted to ask is this the right/best way to do this:

```
    $whatistype = <?php get_bloginfo('site_url'); ?>
    $type = <?php substr( $whatistype, -4);
    <?php if ( $type == "type1 ) 
{ include 'type1list.php'; 
   /* Or code */
}

else 

{ include 'typelistother.php
    /* Or code */
 }
?>
```

Also, I would want this to run only when a blog is created. I will check under the hood at Cets Default plugin, but would it be best to make this a plugin and activate sitewide or make into an MU-plugin? How would I go about making a plugin for the mu-folder (can't find much documentation on it).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but will this be compatible with WP 3.0?  Thought that was the new WP MU ...

Answer (score 1):

This is [the best article](http://www.webworldarticles.com/e/a/title/Developing-Plugins-for-WordPress-MU/) that I've seen on making plugin for MU. Not sure how much has changed since Wordpress 3.x however. For instance the wp-plugin/muplugins/ directory seems to be gone in the Wordpress 3.1 that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a MU plugin with a function that is hooked onto `wpmu_new_blog`.

```
function my_custom_new_blog($blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta)
{
     // depending on if you're using subdomains or sub-directories,
     // match against $domain or $path respectively for 'type'
}
add_action('wpmu_new_blog'), 'my_custom_new_blog', 10, 6);
```

Just create a PHP file, name it what you like, throw in the standard [WordPress plugin headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers) (not required, purely for information in the plugins admin screen) and then drop it in the **root** of `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

If you want to break up your code from a single file, place everything inside `wp-content/mu-plugins/my-directory` - anything in there won't be touched by WP - but keep your single PHP file still in the root, using it to load the rest of your code when it needs it.

Comment: Hey, this helped a lot. Thanks a lot for the tutorial! DeadMedic, you might be single-handedly keeping us WP newbies afloat.